# What is a simple way to explain why best range airspeed is below normal cruise airspeed?

Tags: aircraft-performance, airspeed

Without using complex mathematics, please explain why best range airspeed is less than normal cruise airspeed.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47369/62) might be helpful. You might also like to check out the [tour] if you're new to the site.

Comment: I thought it was a good question.  Can you provide an example of how you might rephrase this to be more specific?

Answer (score 6):

Normal cruise is a compromise between being fuel efficient while getting to your destination at a reasonable speed.  It all comes down to drag; the faster you go the more parasitic drag you pick up and economy suffers.

Just like in your car - if you wanted to squeeze max efficiency (range) out of a trip you could drive at 55mph on the freeway.  In fact you could even make it law!  But, people are generally willing to burn a little more fuel to get there faster.

Comment: Also in commercial operation, the crew is paid by the hour and flying faster also means flying more miles each day and that means more revenue.

Comment: Yes, good point Jan!